# Testing the Account Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

There are surprisingly very few search-engine results for this, but I wanted to know what are the best ways to go about unit testing the Account Controller when using ASP.NET MVC4?

Comment: stepping through the code? What do you mean?

Comment: No, I mean setting up the code in order to login a user and test actions of the controller. The WebSecurity class defined under WebMatrix is what initializes the Simple Membership and takes care of authorization. However, the WebMatrix reference is not acceptable and unrecognizable in the unit test projects.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs !

Comment: Thanks for that... I am specifically asking for AccountController because the test throws an exception when using methods of class WebSecurity that this controller(provided by default in internet application) uses.

Answer (score 0):

use MVC unity with services and the moq framework - properly setup it lets you mock database access